# Uso do getter e setter no Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Não consigo entender a real necessidade de se utilizar o Get/Set para o caso abaixo, o qual, mesmo eu deixando a variável *comodo* privada, eu ainda poderia modificá-la pelo uso de métodos.

```
class casa {
  int comodos = 4;
}

void main() {
  casa casa1 = casa();
  casa1.comodos = 10;
  print(casa1.comodos);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caro @Aiken, se fizer pelos métodos poderá modificar por métodos você pode tratar a entrada, permitindo somente valores "corretos" para a regra/lógica da classe. **Isso é o básico em "visibilidade" em OO com variáveis** (leia sobre a visibilidade de variáveis no final da resposta, acaso não saiba como usar em Dart).

**Você** é quem irá definir o que pode e o que não pode, já se for `public` poderá "tudo" (no caso qualquer valor `int` valido/aceitável). Agora imagine que sua intenção de `comodos` fosse um range limitado de 5 a 50, qualquer um poderia colocar 4 ou menos, 51 ou mais, como valores se for "public", se fizer privado e tratar por um método *set da vida* então uma IF será mais que o suficiente para resolver a regra do range de limite, exemplo:

```
import 'dart:io';

class casa
{
  int _comodos = 4;

  setComodos(int value) {
    if (value < 2 || value > 50) {
        throw("Numero de comodos inválidos");
    } else {
        _comodos = value;
    }
  }

  comodos() {
    return _comodos;
  }
}

void main() {
    casa casa1 = new casa();
    casa1.setComodos(10); //10 comodos
    print(casa1.comodos());
}
```

Se fizer assim:

```
    casa casa1 = new casa();
    casa1.setComodos(100); //100 comodos
    print(casa1.comodos());
```

Vai emitir uma exception customizada que informa que o numero de comodos é invalido, algo como:

```
Unhandled exception:
Numero de comodos inválidos
#0      casa.setComodos (file:///home/brcontainer/prog.dart:9:6)
#1      main (file:///home/brcontainer/prog.dart:22:11)
#2      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:261)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:148)
```

---

### Sobre privado (visibilidade de variaveis) no Dart

Dart tratará variaveis como privadas desde que a classe esteja em uma lib a parte e use o underline/underscore como prefixo, se a classe for declarada no mesmo documento do `main()`, veja a documentação:

- https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility

Comment: Dart não usa getters e setters como Java, Dart usa getters e setters como C#. Se mais tarde o programador quiser adicionar uma regra de validação, ele poderá sem ter refatorar o código para receber os valores através de métodos. Não acredito que exista razão para criar getters e setters em Dart quando você não precisa de validação, talvez tenha sido um mal conselho.

Comment: Caro @user140828 não ficou claro para mim que o autor falava de *métodos especiais* , me pareceu que ele falava de Get e Set no sentido de setar por métodos ao invés de diretamente, aliais se for o caso dos *métodos especiais* ai seria outra coisa, mas como não esta bem descrito na pergunta se são eles ou se não então não vou editar a resposta ainda. Não entendi sobre o mal conselho, expliquei a questão de quando necessidade de uma regra faria sentido usar privado, quando não tiver "regra" então não tem porque.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia,

No dart a refatoração é simplificada, entendo que caso não exista nenhum controle sobre o acesso ao membro, poderá tratá-lo como público, e se a regra de negócio se alterar ao longo do tempo, poderá transformar o membro em privado e declarar os métodos acessadores.

1º Podemos começar com o atributo Público

```
class casa
{
  int comodos = 4;

}
void main() {
    casa casa1 = new casa();
    casa1.comodos = 10; //10 comodos
    print(casa1.comodos);
}
```

2º Após podemos refatorar e modificar a sua visibilidade, sem alterar as dependências.

```
class casa
{
  int _comodos = 4;

  set comodos(int value) {
    if (value < 2 || value > 50) {
        throw("Numero de comodos inválidos");
    } else {
        _comodos = value;
    }
  }

  int get comodos => _comodos;
 
}

void main() {
    casa casa1 = new casa();
    casa1.comodos = 10; //10 comodos
    print(casa1.comodos);
}
```